# Use exploded variable in query without having to loop

Tags: php, mysql

How can I run a query with multiple where clauses depending on an exploded variable (array)?

```
$original = "123,44,55,66";
$exploded = explode(",", $original);
foreach($exploded as $var)
{
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT name FROM my_table WHERE id = $var");
}
```

I don't want to use a foreach loop for the query itself because it uses a lot of resources and slows the loading time for the page by a lot, so how can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check by in query so you will get result without foreach loop

Query:

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT name FROM my_table WHERE id in (123,44,55,66) ");
```

Answer (score 3):

As per your code, every time your query gets overwrite and thus you'll get the last selected data. You can get the result by using `IN` operator.
Instead, try this :-

```
$original = "123,44,55,66";
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT name FROM my_table WHERE id in ($original)");
```